# Вставка символа в произвольное место консоли

Tags: c++

Как в c++ вставить символ в произвольное место консоли?

Comment: Зависит от системы. На *nix, [ANSI кода](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/) можно использовать, на Windows, наверно, API специальное нужно использовать (SetConsoleCursorPosition).

Comment: @VladD: похоже что существует ограничение в 4 комментария на один ответ. Так что если остались вопросы, [спрашивайте отдельно](http://hashcode.ru/questions/ask/)

Comment: @jfs: Да, ограничение существует, в отличие от SO. Но старые комментарии можно удалять — так обычно здесь ведутся дискуссии.

Собственно задавать отдельный вопрос для прояснения туманного комментария не особо имеет смысл, т. к. этот вопрос не приносит пользы сообществу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам стандарт C++ не позволяет этого делать (например, потому, что программа должна корректно работать с перенаправлением ввода-вывода). Поэтому вам придётся использовать системно-зависимые решения.

- Под Windows воспользуйтесь WinAPI: [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- Под Unix-системами посмотрите в сторону библиотеки [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

---

Под Windows вы не сможете описанным образом вывести символ в *последнюю* позицию *последней* строки консоли, так как после вывода курсор переместится, и консоль отскроллируется вверх. Чтобы вывести символ без перемещения курсора, воспользуйтесь функцией [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), или посмотрите, как работать со свойствами [экранного буфера](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([`ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

---

Не забудьте, что при прямой работе с консолью вам не стоит полагаться на высокоуровневый ввод/вывод (`std::cin`/`std::cout`/`std::cerr`, `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`, `read(0, ...)`/`write(1, ...)` и т. п.): вместе оба метода работать не будут.

Comment: Если ввоод-вывод перенаправлен, то программа может автоматически менять характеристики вывода (например, размер буфера для стандартных потоков обычно меняется (по-строчно, если вывод в терминал и по-блочно если вывод перенаправлен в файл)) так что это не является причиной. `colorama` пакет в Питоне ведёт себя именно так: он трансформирует ANSI кода в выводе в подходящие WinAPI вызовы, если вывод в консоль идёт и `colorama` просто удаляет эти кода, если вывод перенаправлен.

Comment: @jfs: Может в рамках стандарта C++?

Comment: C99 стандарт (§7.21.3.7) явно говорит об интерактивных девайсах (определяется реализацией) и буферах стандартных потоков. По умолчанию можно смешивать С stdio ввод-вывод и С++ стандартные потоки, поэтому либо они используют один и тот же буфер (со всеми вытекающими последствиями, в частности подчинение С стандарту) или реализация симулирует это. Так что C++ программа, подчиняющаяся стандарту, автоматически меняет характеристики вывода по умолчанию в зависимости от того перенаправлен вывод или нет.

Comment: @jfs: ОП явно упоминает C++, а не C. По модулю этого, в любом случае платформо-зависимая манипуляция консольным буфером идёт в обход потоков ввода-вывода с их буферизацией. (И разумеется возможные перенаправления на неё не оказывают никакого влияния.)

Не думаю, что есть в рамках стандарта существует способ проверить, перенаправлены ли stdin/stdout.

Comment: Мой предыдущий комментарий явно говорит, почему C++ следует C в данном случае (собственно он целиком этому посвящён. Как этого можно не заметить, я не понимаю). Проверка перенаправлен ли вывод зависит от *реализации* (т.е. даже на одной платформе может быть разное поведение). Потоки полностью буферезированны тогда и только тогда когда они не подсоединены к интерактивному девайсу. Суть этих заметок, что утверждение в ответе *"например, потому, что программа должна корректно работать с перенаправлением ввода-вывода"* не точно, потому что C++ программы *уже* могут менять своё поведение (см. выше

Comment: @jfs: Ну, вы упоминаете стандарт С, а не С++ (а C++ _не_ есть надмножество C и _не_ подчиняется его стандарту).

Попробую объяснить суть текста из ответа. Если бы программа могла выводить данные на консоль, то этим поощрялся бы код, который _не работает_ в случае перенаправления потока вывода. По поводу вашего возражения, не могли бы вы предоставить код, подтверждающий ваше утверждение?

Comment: Да, я упоминаю С стандарт в первом предложении, а затем во втором объясняю почему С++ обязан вести себя также в этом случае (С++11 говорит что `sync_with_stdio` возвращает `true` после первого вызова). Любая С++ программа, которая явно не изменяет настройки стандартных потоков, подходит в качестве примера.

Comment: @jfs: То, что стандартная библиотека может менять внутренние настройки в зависимости того, как запущена программа — понятно. Но каким образом это противоречит моему утверждению? Объясните, не пропуская «очевидных» переходов.